# Randomized algorithm for computing trapezoidal decomposition.

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

In the his paper [*A simple and fast incremental randomized algorithm for computing trapezoidal decompositions and for triangulating polygons*](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/A%20Simple%20and%20fast.pdf) (Computational Geometry: Theory and Applications, 1:51–64, 1991), Siedel discusses following algorithm for finding out trapezoidation and query structure cost.

1. Generate a random order $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n$ of the segments of $P$.
2. Generate $T_1$ and $Q_1$ [initialization].
3. for $h = 1$ to $\log^∗ n$ do

   a. for $i = N(h−1) + 1$ to $N(h)$ do:
   Insert segment $e_i$, producing $T_i$ and $Q_i$ from $T_{i − 1}$ and $Q_{S i − 1}$.

   b. Trace $P$ through $T_{N(h)}$ to locate the endpoints of all $e_j$, for $j > N(h)$.
4. for $i = N(\log^∗ n) + 1$ to $n$ do:
   Insert $e_i$, producing $T_i$ and $Q_i$ from $T_{i − 1}$ and $Q_{S i − 1}$.

The paper says that step 4 is similar to step 3a so why not run the step 4 from $i=1$ to $n$ and perform location of points $\log^*n$ times in step 3?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!